# Angular routes not accessible through POSTMAN

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular9

I'm using angular 9 for a project which works fine in browser. I am trying to access a route through POSTMAN but I'm getting an error. How to make a route reachable through CLI?

Here are my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: JoinClassComponent},
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'class-ended', component: ClassEndedComponent},
  // otherwise redirect to home
  {path:'**', component: JoinClassComponent},
];
```

Here is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-class-ended',
  templateUrl: './class-ended.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./class-ended.component.css']
})
export class ClassEndedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
            const classID: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('meetingID');
           //rest of the logic
         }
}
```

**URL Not working in POSTMAN**

[image]

**URL working in browser**

[image: URL working in browser]

**/ route working in POSTMAN**

[image]

Comment: Build your project and deploy it on a web server

Comment: Build not required to test routes. May be the problem with component name declaration . Please show your component class

Comment: did you call this url by browser?

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you make the request? When I call my Angular app in Postman I only see index.html - the Javascript that builds the HTML doesn't run.

Comment: I'm making an http GET request from a server to this url for further processing. But it is not working so I just wanted to test through postman whether this url is reachable through GET request or not.

Comment: angular application serves the request and response page contents are provided in the form of javascript files. so the index. html file will not contain the actual html source, this will render by the browser from the downloaded js file. so the page source onlyt contains the links of respective js files downloaded by the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot work, because Postman sends the URL `localhost:4200/class-ended` request to your server - and your server does not know anything about this URL.
In comparison: when you enter the same URL in your browser, your angular application will handle the request.

Angular builds [Single-Page applications](https://blog.angular-university.io/why-a-single-page-application-what-are-the-benefits-what-is-a-spa/), so on your server, you will only have one `index.html` file in the root directory: i.e. when you visit `localhost:4200`, your web-server returns `index.html` to your browser (and this html file includes script tags to load your javascript source code).

When you enter `localhost:4200/class-ended` in your browser, angular will be notified that the URL has changed and check the route configuration if the route `/class-ended` exists. If so, the [angular-router](https://angular.io/guide/router) will "navigate" to this route: i.e. it will display that component in the router-outlet.
But this **does not** send any request to the server (and as mentioned above, this would not work, because `class-ended` does not exist on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Postman is an API(application programming interface) development tool which helps to build, test and modify APIs.It has the ability to make various types of HTTP requests(GET, POST, PUT, PATCH), saving environments for later use, converting the API to code for various languages.

So use it to test your API, not to call your HTML pages.

I hope It is helpful for you. :)